# Resultado de base de datos me trae solo el nombre y no el apellido

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema raro, tengo un sistema de tareas donde las personas crean tareas y despues tiene que editar esas tareas, en la pagina editar traigo los campos de la base de datos pero lo raro es que el campo nombre que tiene el nombre completo trae solo en primer nombre y no el nombre completo, es muy raro no se que pueda estar pasando.
Les comparto el codigo con imagenes.

**Consulta Sql**

```
        $base = "SELECT * FROM tareas WHERE id='$id'";
        $nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
        $crow= mysqli_fetch_array($nquery);
```

**Html que recibe la consulta**

```
  echo "<label for='nombre' class='form-label'><strong>Nombre</strong></label>
<select class='form-select' name='nombre' required>
<option value=".$crow['nombre'].">".$crow['nombre']."</option>
<option value='Fernando Bielochercovzky'>Fernando Bielochercovzky</option>
<option value='Marcos Buchini'>Marcos Buchini</option>
<option value='Jose Giorgis'>Jose Giorgis</option>
</select>
<div class='invalid-feedback'>Elija el nombre</div>
</div>
```

El campo value trae solo el nombre pero el otro campo con el combre trae el nombre completo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta separando el apellido, cosa que en la base de datos esta todo junto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega comillas simples antes de las comillas dobles que están en tu `value` -> `<option value='".$crow['nombre']."'>".$crow['nombre']."</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltan las comillas simples. El navegador trata de componer eso, y al haber un espacio entre nombre y apellido, coloca el nombre como `value` y el apellido como propiedad

Tú tienes esto:

```
<option value=".$crow['nombre'].">".$crow['nombre']."</option>
```

Y debes cambiarlo por:

```
//            v-------------------v--Estas comillas faltan           
<option value='".$crow['nombre']."'>".$crow['nombre']."</option>
```

Comment: Excelente, era eso si. Muchas gracias

Answer (score -2):

El problema que estás experimentando es que los valores de los atributos en las etiquetas HTML deben estar entre comillas. En tu caso, cuando la variable $crow['nombre'] contiene un espacio (por ejemplo, un nombre y un apellido), el navegador interpreta el espacio como el final del atributo value. Para solucionar este problema, simplemente debes agregar comillas alrededor del valor en el atributo value de la etiqueta option

Comment: ¿En qué difiere tu respuesta de la aceptada? Por cierto, y por las dudas: [Política temporal: CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462).

Comment: que añadas comillas simples al atributo: '".$crow['nombre']."'

Comment: [Dice lo mismo](/a/589439).

Comment: Y esta pregunta ni debería ser respondida, son solo errores tipográficos, existe un voto de cierre para eso, basta con decírselo en los comentarios.

Comment: Pues sí @Cris223511.dev, tipográficos* (?

Comment: @padaleiana Sí, ya lo había editado jeje

Comment: tiene razon los chicos, la respuesta ya fue publicada, solo respondes lo mismo.